# Why is the first value of a Rails find_or_create_by block always nil in database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I am using a `find_or_create_by` block.

If a TrainingEvent record with the `webinar_id` that's being passed as an argument is not found, Rails should create a new TrainingEvent with all of the attributes passed in the block.

Rails creates the record but the first attribute is always nil in the database.

Rails 5.2.0

ruby 2.4.1p111

```
TrainingEvent.find_or_create_by(webinar_key: '2345') do |training_event|
  training_event.start_date_time = '2018-07-04 12:00:00',
  training_event.end_date_time = '2018-07-04 13:00:00',
  training_event.published = true,
  training_event.hidden_from_list = false,
  training_event.training_template_id = 349,
  training_event.organizer_key = '6789'
end
```

start_date_time is not in the SQL and ends up being nil in the database. No matter which attribute is first in the block, the value is always nil.

[image]

Comment: (1) Please don't include screen shots of text in your questions, the text itself would be much easier to read and work with. (2) Why do you have all those trailing commas in the block?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The commas that [mu is too short](https://stackoverflow.com/users/479863/mu-is-too-short) spotted are what's actually causing the problem here.

This is interpreted by Ruby as trying to assign an array to `start_date_time` with a side effect of setting all the other attributes along the way. As this isn't a valid value for the field it ends up remaining as `nil`.

It looks like this stems from a slight misunderstanding:

> Rails should create a new TrainingEvent with all of the attributes passed in the block

The block isn't for passing a *list* of attributes. The block is code which in the case of `create` is passed the new model object so that you can do anything you'd like with it prior to it being saved. Remove the commas and you'll be fine!

---

If you're curious, here's a simpler example that demonstrates how your code is being interpreted:

```
> x = 1, y = 2
```

This results in `x` having the array value `[1, 2]` and `y` having the value `2`

Comment: Shame that the `start_date_time=` method (and other timestamp mutators from ActiveRecord) didn't complain loudly when fed values they don't know what to do with. Quietly converting the nonsense to `nil` is terrible default behavior.

Comment: Thank you for the thorough explanation, @mikej. You are absolutely correct. Works like a charm now.